# How to import PyQt5 in QGIS 2.99?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5

I installed QGIS by using OsGeo4W64. I can use pyqgis PyQt5 version in PyCharm. However, when I write scripts in python console in QGIS, it does not accept. I looked the version of QGIS. It says developper version 2.99 and PyQt5.9.

When I write in python console:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 64, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\codeop.py", line 168, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 1
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

I wrote the python console like that:

```
from PyQt.QtCore import *
```

and it works!

Comment: It changed again because in my case it works with: `from PyQt5.QtCore import *`  and `from PyQt5.QtGui import *`

Comment: Yes you are right!